# presenting age more than [number] from birth date in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called dependent:

[image]

And now I need to present the dependents more than 40 years old for example.

P.S. Right now I am trying to use `DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), dependent.bdate)/365.25` function, but still can't present it. How to do this?

Comment: How would you treat that `0000-00-00` value?

Comment: @Phil it will be just undefined (null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `bdate` is an actual `DATE` column, I think it would be easier to create a date 40 years prior to the current date and select where `bdate` is less-than or equal to that date

```
WHERE dependent.bdate <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 40 YEAR)
```